# COMMENT ON generates ORA-00905: missing keyword through EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help on figuring out the problem with the ORA-00905: missing keyword ORA-06512: at line 73

When it says line 73 it actually refers to the sql statement itself at line 56. However, I am using this same script with a different table which working perfectly.
 By changing the schema, table and column name I keep getting this error. I have be experimenting with several versions and also using fetch into cursor. 
 It keeps saying the sql statement has missing keyword but it is working on another script with the same line. I am hoping somebody could help me here. This is my first time posting on this forum and I am hoping someday I could contribute to this great community. Thank you in advance!

```
DECLARE
--CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE setcomment
--IS

         CURSOR cur IS 
           SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, OWNER 
           FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
           WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SSAN' 
           ORDER BY OWNER ASC, TABLE_NAME ASC, COLUMN_NAME ASC;

         c_schema_name           DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%type; 
         c_table_name                DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%type;
         c_column_name            DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%type;


        --This is a variable name to concatenate column names from <c_schema_name>.<c_table_name>.<c_column_name>
        col_name VARCHAR(250) ;                    
        --This is a variable to hold SQL statement and the message to be commented 
        sql_stmt1 VARCHAR(2000) ;
        msg VARCHAR(250)    := ' '' Comment going here '' '; 

 BEGIN

     --Looping r cursor through cur cursor. Retrieving a row of record at a time
     FOR  r in cur LOOP


         c_schema_name := r.owner;
         c_table_name := r.table_name;
         c_column_name := r.column_name;                    

         --Concatenate all the column names into a single column name. 
          col_name := c_schema_name||'.'||c_table_name||'.'||c_column_name;

         sql_stmt1  :=   'COMMENT ON COLUMN '|| col_name ||' IS ''Comment going here '' ' ;

         -- sql_stmt1  :=   'COMMENT ON COLUMN '|| col_name ||' IS '||msg;

           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt1;
          --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMENT ON COLUMN '|| c_schema_name||'.'||c_table_name||'.'||c_column_name || ' IS '' Comment going here '' ' ;

           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('COMMENT ON ' || col_name   || ' procedure completed....');


    END LOOP;


 END;
  /
```

---

If you still cannot find a source of the error, then create a log table, run the below code, and display (select) all error entries from the table
Then try to manually run the command.
Does you user have an appriopriate privileges to comment on tables in other schemas ? It can have a privilege to SELECT from DBA_TAB_COLS, but that doesn't mean that it can modify other schemas/tables.

```
CREATE TABLE log_errors( error_msg varchar2(4000));

DECLARE
         CURSOR cur IS 
           SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, OWNER 
           FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
           WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SSAN' 
           ORDER BY OWNER ASC, TABLE_NAME ASC, COLUMN_NAME ASC;

        col_name VARCHAR(250) ;                    
        sql_stmt1 VARCHAR(2000) ;
        msg VARCHAR(250)    := 'Comment going here'; 

 BEGIN
     FOR  r in cur LOOP
          col_name := '"'|| r.OWNER ||'"."'||r.TABLE_NAME||'"."'||r.COLUMN_NAME||'"';
          sql_stmt1 := 'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || col_name || ' IS ''' || msg || '''';
          BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt1;
          EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                INSERT INTO log_errors( error_msg ) VALUES ( sql_stmt1 );
          END;
    END LOOP;
 END;
  / 

  SELECT * FROM log_errors;
```

Comment: thank you krokodilko for correcting the post. It looked messy earlier.

Comment: Hi Krokodilko, thank you for the follow up. Yes I have the privilege to access DBA_TAB_COLUMNS. This think is driving me nuts. I could finish a complicated Java program by now and yet I couldn't figure a one liner issue. I am still new to PL/SQL but I gotta do this one. I added a custom error message but it doesn't show me much. I guess, this weekend is the Comment ON theme, beside watching out for the hurricane or tornado.

Comment: IT WORKS after I grant a permission to my own personal username through SQLPLUS. When I created the username I forgot to provide all the permission to access all the DML and the tables. Thank you Krokodilko. Actually, looked into it after you mentioned it. Lesson learn is, it is not always the script but also the permission. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mathguy's answer - your script will fail if any of the tables has been created using [quoted identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129)

> **Database Object Naming Rules**
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent
>   the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted
>   identifier.
>
> - **A quoted identifier** begins and ends with double quotation marks (").
>     If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
>     use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - **A nonquoted identifier** is not surrounded by any punctuation.
>
> You can use either quoted or nonquoted identifiers to name any
>   database object. However, database names, global database names, and
>   database link names are always case insensitive and are stored as
>   uppercase. If you specify such names as quoted identifiers, then the
>   quotation marks are silently ignored.

Simple practical example - a name of the first table is nonquoted identifier, a name of the second table is quoted identifier :

```
CREATE TABLE table_one (
  SSAN int
);

CREATE TABLE "TaBle @#% TWO" (
  SSAN int
);

SELECT 'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || '.' || COLUMN_NAME || ' IS ''My superb comment''' 
       As my_comment_command
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SSAN' ;

MY_COMMENT_COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------
COMMENT ON COLUMN SCOTT.TABLE_ONE.SSAN IS 'My superb comment'
COMMENT ON COLUMN SCOTT.TaBle @#% TWO.SSAN IS 'My superb comment'
```

It's obvious, that the second command will fail.

---

But if you use quotes in your script, then everything will work fine:

```
SELECT 'COMMENT ON COLUMN "' || OWNER || '"."' || TABLE_NAME || '"."' || COLUMN_NAME || '" IS ''My superb comment''' 
       As my_comment_command
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SSAN' ;

MY_COMMENT_COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCOTT"."TABLE_ONE"."SSAN" IS 'My superb comment'
COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCOTT"."TaBle @#% TWO"."SSAN" IS 'My superb comment'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail description not just pointing out the potential defect on the line. It will give me something to look into this weekend. I will try this one right now.

Comment: On the top I changed the object refers by cursor as 

   c_schema_name := r.OWNER;
   c_table_name := r.TABLE_NAME;
   c_column_name := r.COLUMN_NAME;                    

sql_stmt1  := 'COMMENT ON COLUMN "' || c_schema_name || '"."' || c_table_name || '"."' || c_column_name || ' IS "Comment here ''  ' ;

However, I am still getting the same missing key error message. However, thank you for pointing out the single and double quote.

Comment: This line, SELECT 'COMMENT ON COLUMN "'|| OWNER ||'"."'|| TABLE_NAME||'"."'||COLUMN_NAME||''' IS ''comment goes here''' from dba_tab_columns where COLUMN_NAME = 'SSAN'; 

will list out all the columns that has the 'SSAN'. If I make a literal comment using the result set from above one at a time it will work. However, it doesn't work dynamically in the pl/sql. I am still loking.

Comment: I've changed my answer - I've appended a script which will log all wrong commands, and also some tips how to deal with it.

Comment: The log error is definitely a good idea too. Thank you. It is just that Oracle error message is not very specific and too generic.  However, it is always a good habit to add it in.